# Argument's name shadows keyword in module argparse python

Tags: python, argparse

When I try to get argument with flag "--from" from argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args() an error occurs. IDE says that "from" is import statement and the code is unreachable:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='cache_wiki.py',
                                     description='Find shortest path between links')
parser.add_argument('--from', required=True, help='page to start search with')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.from)
```

It is ok with another name:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='cache_wiki.py',
                                     description='Find shortest path between links')
parser.add_argument('--f', required=True, help='page to start search with')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.f)
```

but I really need to use flag "--from".

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest

Comment: The code isn't unreachable; `args.from` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

I would ignore the IDE here. True, you cannot use `args.from`, but that's just a *syntactic* limitation. You can still access the attribute using, for example, `getattr(args, 'from')`.

You can also override the default destination name so that you can use the option `--from`, but set a different attribute:

```
...
parser.add_argument('--from',
                    required=True,
                    dest='from_',
                    help='page to start search with')

args = p.parse_args(['--from', 'foo'])
assert args.from_ == 'foo'
```